# Translate to Objective-C from Objective-C++

Tags: c++, objective-c, coremidi

I have this code in a .mm

`void MyMIDINotifyProc(const MIDINotification *message, void *refCon);`

which goes with this line

`MIDIClientCreate((CFStringRef)@"MidiMonitor MIDI Client", MyMIDINotifyProc, self, &client);`

and then the MyMIDINotifyProc gets called from CoreMIDI.

Without changing the file extension to .m, I translated to an Obj-C signature:

```
@interface MidiInput (Private) 
    -(void) MyMIDINotifyProc:(const MIDINotification *)message reference:(void *)refCon;
@end
```

which compiles, but then I have no idea what to do with the `MIDIClientCreate` line. As is, it produces `"MyMIDINotifyProc" was not declared in this scope`. It's supposed to be of type `void *`... And the docs are 100% clear that it's `A refCon passed back to notifyRefCon` ([link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreMidi/Reference/MIDIServices_Reference/Reference/reference.html)).

Is this problem solvable in Obj-C alone? I imagine I'd have to translate the C++ stuff to C, in which case I would just leave it alone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MIDIClientCreate` expects an ordinary C function as its callback.  You can't pass it an Objective-C method because the calling convention is different (in C terms, the first two parameters to an Objective-C method are `self` and `_cmd` - the selector - which will not be there for an ordinary C function).

The usual way around this is to create a C function that acts as a shim and explicitly pass self as a parameter.  The shim function then immediately sends the objective-C message.  I'm not familiar with this library, but it looks like `refCon` is a parameter designed for exactly this sort of thing.  So in your `.m` file you need a function like this.

```
static void MyMIDINotifyProc(const MIDINotification *message, void *refCon)
{
    [(id) refCon MIDINotify: message];
}
```

You also need a method to do the actual stuff:

```
-(void) MIDINotify: (const MIDINotification*) message
{
    // do stuff
}
```

And you call MIDIClientCreate exactly as you were doing originally.

Comment: Thanks, +1 and I'll accept this answer once I digest it (or once XCode does ;)).